# Editing nested files in child-theme

Tags: wordpress

i'm editing an existing "commercial" theme.
Unfortunately it's full of bugs and i need to get rid of that.
So i started working on a child-theme to continue receiving updates from the theme creator.
Everything works as intended but i can't get rid on editing nested files.

For example this is a file i would like to edit

```
<theme-folder>/inc/header/header.php
```

if i create the same directory hierarchy in the child folder, the new file doesn't override the old one.
Am i missing something?
Thanks

P.S. i know there are some solutions but i cannot edit the main theme template

SOLUTION

I actually solved registering updated files in function.php by adding

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/subroot/file.php' );
```

Comment: child files are only loaded with `locate_template()`. if the theme load it by another way (like a simple `require`) it cannot work.

Comment: Did you activate the new theme? Since the child theme should include the parent theme.

Comment: I found a solution and updated the topic